# What's the best to method call a Webservice from ASP?

Tags: web-services, asp-classic

Note: not ASP.NET.

I've read about various methods including using SOAPClient (is this part of the standard Windows 2003 install?), ServerXMLHTTP, and building up the XML from scratch and parsing the result manually.

Has anyone ever done this?  What did you use and would you recommend it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, since the web service talks XML over standard HTTP you could roll your own using the latest XML parser from Microsoft. You should make sure you have the latest versions of MSXML and XML Core Services (see [Microsoft Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570309.aspx)).

```
<% 
    SoapUrl = "http://www.yourdomain.com/yourwebservice.asmx" 
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
    xmlhttp.open "GET", SoapUrl, false 
    xmlhttp.send()
    Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
    set xmlhttp = nothing 
%>
```

Here is a good tutorial on [ASPFree.com](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP/Consuming-a-WSDL-Webservice-from-ASP/)

Answer (score 1):

We use the MS Soap Toolkit version 3 here.  Seems to work ok (I only wrote the services).

Comment: I'd avoid this.  Its deprecated, not recommend for server 2003, uses MSXML4 and I'm not even sure it uses WinHTTP but may use WinINET instead.